# Robots.txt taking out form keys

Tags: robots.txt

I was wondering if someone would be able to take a look at this to tell me if I configured it correctly? I am not trying to block all parameters (?) but just the ones with `hsformkey`. Here is how i wrote the directive. I tested it in search console and it says it is blocked, but I'm not sure I trust it.

```
Disallow: *?hsFormKey*
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Robots.txt is a convention that many automated web crawlers (most often used by search engines to index sites) use to tell them any pages you don't want them to crawl. It's a fairly loose convention, and different crawlers support different features.

The original documentation, which is the closest there is to a universal standard, doesn't include the concept of "wildcards" or "globbing". Per "[The Web Robots Pages](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)":

> Note also that globbing and regular expression are not supported in either the User-agent or Disallow lines. The '*' in the User-agent field is a special value meaning "any robot". Specifically, you cannot have lines like "User-agent: *bot*", "Disallow: /tmp/*" or "Disallow: *.gif".

That being said, it's a common addition that many crawlers do support. For example, in [Google's documentation of they directives they support](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en&ref_topic=6061961), they describe pattern matching support that does handle using `*` as a wildcard. Note that since `Disallow` directives are beginning-of-URL instructions anyway, the asterisk at the end doesn't do anything useful.

The thing to keep in mind is that the exclusion rules work directly on the URL, not on any path or conventions used by your web server or application framework. While your application may treat characters like `?` and `&` as delimiting parameter information (as it's a pretty common and standard thing to do), the web crawler is just interpreting the entire URL. Also, URL paths are case sensitive. So, you are excluding the web crawler from loading any URL that has `?hsFormKey` in it, but not excluding URLs with `?somethingelse=value&hsFormKey=123` in them, nor are you excluding URLs with `?hsformkey` in them. This may be exactly what you want, but I'm not sure of your requirements. And as I said, it will only be effective for those crawlers that recognize this style of wildcard.

Also be aware that robots.txt only prevents loading of the excluded URLs by crawlers. Excluded URLs can still show up other places that people can find (bookmarked links, links shared on social media, etc.) and can still show up in search engines. Google [explicitly states](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en) they will still index and list a URL, even if they're not allowed to crawl it:

> While Google won't crawl or index the content blocked by `robots.txt`, we might still find and index a disallowed URL from other places on the web. As a result, the URL address and, potentially, other publicly available information such as anchor text in links to the site can still appear in Google search results. You can stop your URL from appearing in Google Search results completely by using other URL blocking methods, such as password-protecting the files on your server or using the noindex meta tag or response header.